# how to force change the primary button text color bootstrap 4 by scss

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I'ma tring to change the `.btn-primary` **text** color.

I changed the background color on `_variables.scss` by added the next line:

```
$primary: #a1c1b6;
```

but I couldn't change the text color, I tried all of those and nothing worked

```
// not working
$primary-color: #fff;
$primary-btn-color: #fff;
$primary-text-color: #fff;
$primary-btn-text-color: #fff;
```

I noticed also that the text color changed automatically when the background changed

so how to force the text color to be white or red for example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit the `_variables.scss` file or other files. You can use `!important` keyword to force something to change.

it can be done like this:
`$primary-color: #fff !important;`